# ASP.Net Offload Page Processing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-4.0

I have a current issue with one of our applications which is called by a 3rd Party.

The 3rd Party sends data (contained in a querystring) to a URL in our website and they must receive a OK response from the page within 5 seconds to verify that the call was received.

The page itself does a lot of processing of the data that is sent by the 3rd Party in the Page_Load function.  It's possible that this is taking more than 5 seconds and therefore the page is not rendering until the processing is completed which in turn causes the 3rd Party to continue sending the data back to us multiple times as there system assumes we have not received it.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to offload the processing of the data so that I can render the page almost as soon as the 3rd Party calls the URL?

Note that there are no controls on the page, its purely a blank page with code behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right in assuming the 3rd party is just calling the page to send up the data, i.e they don't care about the result?

There are a couple of approaches that come to mind, a simple approach would be to dispatch the work as it comes in onto a thread and return "OK" immediately leaving the thread to carry on working.
The second approach would be to write the incoming query-string data to a file or database table and let an external process periodically pick it up and process batches of them.

Comment: Yes that's correct, we do not send any data back to them, its basically a one way call from them to us.  

I would rather not put the data into the database as its time critical, I was thinking of the thread approach and will try and prototype that up today to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to retrieve the data after the page has loaded.